# adding up columns in pandas dataframe results in categorical index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
ps_yd_1            $0^{th} - 25^{th}$  $25^{th} - 50^{th}$  \
ps_variable_1                                                   
$0^{th} - 25^{th}$             47.566800            23.441332   
$25^{th} - 50^{th}$            32.764905            40.947438   
$50^{th} - 75^{th}$            10.830286            21.435877   
$75^{th} - 100^{th}$           14.388537            33.796734   
ps_yd_1            $50^{th} - 75^{th}$  $75^{th} - 100^{th}$  
ps_variable_1                                                    
$0^{th} - 25^{th}$              21.237253              7.754615  
$25^{th} - 50^{th}$              8.634613             17.653044  
$50^{th} - 75^{th}$             14.684188             53.049650  
$75^{th} - 100^{th}$            13.072976             38.741753
```

I want to add 2 columns to create a new one:

```
df_hmp['a'] = df_hmp['$0^{th} - 25^{th}$'] + df_hmp['$25^{th} - 50^{th}$']
```

but I get this error:

```
*** TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category
```

This is what the index looks like:

```
CategoricalIndex(['$0^{th} - 25^{th}$', '$25^{th} - 50^{th}$',
                  '$50^{th} - 75^{th}$', '$75^{th} - 100^{th}$'],
                 categories=['$0^{th} - 25^{th}$', '$25^{th} - 50^{th}$', '$50^{th} - 75^{th}$', '$75^{th} - 100^{th}$'], ordered=True, name='ps_variable_1', dtype='category')
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please provide sample data that is easy to copy into an IDE.  Particularly in this case, it's not easy to reproduce the conditions that are leading to this problem without lots of reconfiguring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All columns and rows in your dataframe have categorical indexes. If you want to add another column, you must first add another value to the categorical index.

Let's first recreate you dataframe:

```
df_hmp = pd.DataFrame([[47.566800 ,32.764905,10.830286,14.388537],
                 [23.441332,40.947438,21.435877,33.796734],
                 [21.237253,8.634613,14.684188,13.072976],
                 [7.75461,17.653044,53.049650,38.741753]]).T

idx = pd.CategoricalIndex(['$0^{th} - 25^{th}$', '$25^{th} - 50^{th}$',
               '$50^{th} - 75^{th}$', '$75^{th} - 100^{th}$'],
                categories=['$0^{th} - 25^{th}$', '$25^{th} - 50^{th}$',  
               '$50^{th} - 75^{th}$', '$75^{th} - 100^{th}$'], 
               ordered=True, name='ps_variable_1', dtype='category')
df_hmp.columns = idx
df_hmp.index = idx.copy()
df_hmp.columns.name = 'ps_yd_1'
```

Now, manipulate the categorical variable:

```
df_hmp.columns = df_hmp.columns.add_categories('a')
df_hmp['a'] = df_hmp['$0^{th} - 25^{th}$'] + df_hmp['$25^{th} - 50^{th}$']
# Works like charm
```

Comment: thanks @DYZ, I get this error: `*** IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page: what is your pandas version?

Comment: my pandas version is 0.22

Comment: I have 0.23.4, which is not very different. I changed the answer to make it self-contained and as close  to your example as possible. Do you still get the error when you execute it?